# DB2 Select Statement error after for loop in stored procedure

Tags: sql, db2

I've written a stored procedure which uses a for loop to execute a query for a list of views.  It generates a dynamic sql statement for each view inside the for loop and then executes it, which inserts output into a declared temporary table.

The for loop works perfectly and it runs without errors, however if I add a select statement after the END FOR; to get the final output from the temporary table I get the error below. Does anyone have any ideas please?

`Error  16/07/2018 10:43:41 0:00:00.007 DB2 Database Error: ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "select *" was found following "1;      END FOR;    ".  Expected tokens may include:  "<call>".  LINE NUMBER=31.  SQLSTATE=42601`

**SQL Code:**

```
BEGIN
 DECLARE SQLTEXT varchar(500);
 DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.AS_USAGE_RESULTS(
  temp table columns
 );

 FOR v as cur1 cursor for
   select distinct viewname,viewschema
   from syscat.VIEWS
  DO

  SET SQLTEXT = 'Dynamic Insert into temp table here' 

  PREPARE s1 FROM SQLTEXT;
  EXECUTE s1;
 END FOR;

 select *
   from SESSION.AS_USAGE_RESULTS;

 DROP TABLE SESSION.AS_USAGE_RESULTS;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that if you wish to return a result-set from session.as_usage_results, then you must declare a cursor for its select, and open that cursor then end the sproc. This is a FAQ. There are examples in the IBM Db2 Server SAMPLES directory and in the Db2 Knowledge Center.

Inside the sproc, you can either use SELECT ... INTO, or use a select within a cursor, or use a SELECT as part of a SET statement.

You should not drop the session table in the procedure in case the result-set won't be consumed before the table gets dropped.   Either drop the session table elsewhere or use an alternative design.

In your example you don't need cursor cur1, so below I show a stilted artificial example of what your might mean. It is artificial because you can see that the session table is also redundant for this example, but it shows the use of the cursor for the result-set.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

create or replace procedure dynproc1
language sql
specific dynproc1
dynamic result sets 1
BEGIN

    DECLARE v_sqltext varchar(2000);
    DECLARE c1 cursor with return to client for s1;
    DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.AS_USAGE_RESULTS ( viewname varchar(128), viewschema varchar(128) );

    insert into session.as_usage_results(viewname, viewschema) select viewname, viewschema from syscat.views;

    set v_sqltext = 'select * from session.as_usage_results';

    prepare s1 from v_sqltext;

    open c1;
END
@
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm new to Db2 after many years of SQL Server.  i found some of the examples you mention and I've added a DECLARE CURSOR / OPEN CURSOR block after the END FOR; but I still get an error.  Really appreciate your answer and any further ideas you may have!   "SQL0104N  An unexpected token "<cursor declaration>" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "<SQL statement>""

END FOR;
DECLARE c1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CALLER FOR
  select LOGIN_ID,APPL_NAME,SNAPSHOT_DATE,View_Name
  from SESSION.AS_USAGE_RESULTS;

OPEN c1;

Comment: Never mind I discovered DB2 is sensitive the order in which things are declared in a sproc.  moving my cursor declarations to the top has resolved this error.